# Como calcular los días hábiles entre 2 tablas

Tags: sql

actualmente no tengo el conocimiento en SQL SERVER y no se como realizar lo siguiente, actualmente tengo 2 tablas en 1 tengo los datos de los clientes con una fecha de ingreso y en esta tabla debo ingresar los días hábiles (No Sábados, No domingos, No festivos) hasta el día actual, en la otra tabla ya tengo categorizado en el campo contador 1 para los días hábiles y el 0 para (Sábados, domingos, festivos), pero no se de que forma hacer la consulta.

Tabla Clientes:

`SELECT iddocumento ,fecdocumento ,DiasHabiles  FROM Carg_Ampliaciones1`

Tabla Fechas:

`SELECT Fechas, Anio ,Mes ,Dia ,Contador FROM Mae_Fechas`

La idea es que en la tabla (Carg_Ampliaciones1) para el campo (DiasHabiles), me sume el total de días de la tabla Fechas campo Contador, tengo clientes desde el 2014 hasta el día de hoy.

Tabla Carg_Ampliaciones1

| iddocumento | fecdocumento | DiasHabiles |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2795861 | 2020-11-19 16:38:29.000 | NULL |
| 2795082 | 2020-11-19 07:21:18.000 | NULL |
| 2794806 | 2020-11-18 17:23:34.000 | NULL |
| 2793728 | 2020-11-17 19:03:35.000 | NULL |
| 2793678 | 2020-11-17 18:39:49.000 | NULL |

Tabla Fechas

| Fechas | Dia | Contador |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2014-01-01 | Miércoles | 0 |
| 2014-01-02 | Jueves | 1 |
| 2014-01-03 | Viernes | 1 |
| 2014-01-04 | Sábado | 0 |
| 2014-01-05 | Domingo | 0 |

De antemano muchas gracias por el apoyo y conocimiento.

Comment: Hola Diego, en tu tabla Fechas quieres agregar los 365 días del año?

Comment: En la pregunta mencionas que tienes que sumar los dias habiles en tu tabla Carg_Ampliaciones1, pero solo tengo una fecha, cual es el segundo criterio para la suma? o es de la fecha actual a esa fecha? no lo dejas claro en la pregunta

Comment: Hola Villatoro, la idea es que inicie a sumar desde la fecha del campo (FECDOCUMENTO) de la tabla ampliaciones y finalice al día de hoy, entre ese rango de fechas debe sumar..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalmente ese dato, no se guarda en una tabla, se calcula por medio de una función o vista (días hábiles), ya que eso te vale para el día de hoy, pero mañana tendrás que volver a calcularlo.

```
Create Table dbo.carg_ampliaciones1
 (
    iddocumento  int
  , fecdocumento datetime
  , diashabiles  int
 );
GO
Create table dbo.Fechas 
(
    fechas date
  , dia varchar(15)
  , contador bit
);
GO

Insert into dbo.carg_ampliaciones1
(iddocumento, fecdocumento, diashabiles)
values
(2795861,'20201101',null),
(2795082,'20201121',null);
GO
Insert into dbo.Fechas
(fechas, dia, contador)
values
('20201101','Domingo',0),
('20201102','Lunes',1),
('20201103','Martes',1),
('20201104','Miércoles',0),
('20201105','Jueves',1),
('20201106','Viernes',1),
('20201107','Sábado',0),
('20201108','Domingo',0),
('20201109','Lunes',1),
('20201110','Martes',1),
('20201111','Miércoles',0),
('20201112','Jueves',1),
('20201113','Viernes',1),
('20201114','Sábado',0),
('20201115','Domingo',0),
('20201116','Lunes',1),
('20201117','Martes',1),
('20201118','Miércoles',0),
('20201119','Jueves',1),
('20201120','Viernes',1),
('20201121','Sábado',0),
('20201122','Domingo',0),
('20201123','Lunes',1),
('20201124','Martes',1),
('20201125','Miércoles',0),
('20201126','Jueves',1),
('20201127','Viernes',1),
('20201128','Sábado',0),
('20201129','Domingo',0),
('20201130','Lunes',1),
('20201201','Martes',1),
('20201202','Miércoles',0),
('20201203','Jueves',1),
('20201204','Viernes',1),
('20201205','Sábado',0),
('20201206','Domingo',0),
('20201207','Lunes',1),
('20201208','Martes',1);
GO
```

Esta es la reproducción del escenario que planteas, pero sólo con las fechas correspondientes al mes de noviembre y lo que llevamos de diciembre de 2020 y para dos registros de la tabla de cargos. He insertado las fechas en formato ISO para no tener problemas con los determinadas codificaciones regionales asociadas a la conexión yyyyMMdd.

[image: Escenario]

La solución, pasa por evaluar cada registro de la tabla dbo.carg_ampliaciones1 por cada registro de la tabla fechas, donde la fecha de cargos sea mayor o igual que la fecha de fechas siempre y cuando contador sea un día válido.

```
;with cte as (
    Select d.iddocumento, d.fecdocumento, 
    sum(
        case when f.contador = 1 and  cast(d.fecdocumento as date) <= f.fechas 
        then 1 else 0 end
        ) as valor
    from dbo.carg_ampliaciones1 d
        cross join dbo.Fechas f
    group by d.iddocumento, d.fecdocumento
    )
Update d set diashabiles = c.valor 
From dbo.carg_ampliaciones1 d inner join cte c
on d.iddocumento = c.iddocumento;
```

En la tabla de expresión común (cte), se realiza un cross join entre ambas tablas y para cada valor se evalúa en el case que se cumpla lo solicitado. Si este valor para cada registro de la combinación es true entonces se suma un 1.

La suma se agrupa para obtener las filas que contenga cargos, con el valor de esa suma para ese registro.

A la salida del cte lo que hacemos es relacionar ese conjunto con dbo.carg_ampliaciones1 y realizar la update con el valor obtenido.

```
Select d.iddocumento
     , d.fecdocumento
     , d.diashabiles
       From dbo.carg_ampliaciones1 d;
```

[image: Resultado]

[Tablas de expresión común](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/12/18/with-cte-tablas-de-expresion-comun-1/)

Comment: Hola @Javi fer2, mil gracias por la consulta corre muy bien, pero cuando la cargo en base de datos y la ejecuto, los resultados no me coindicen, no se si debo hacer un ajuste o cambio en la estructura del campo (fecdocumento).  para el caso del  iddocumento 2795861 inicia el 2020-11-19 y en mi campo final me registran 1.010 días hábiles, cuando realmente al día de hoy debería dar 12 días hábiles. Si debo crear un campo extra y que tipo de formato debe tener para que calcule bien , me podría servir bastante. mil gracias.

Comment: Lo más importante es saber que estructura de datos tienes. A priori, no dice nada la imagen sobre la fecha hora (fecdocumento). Puede ser un datetime, o un varchar(n)), ya que  Mira en la base de datos que tipo es fecdocumento.

Comment: Hola @javi Fer2, el campo esta estructurado como                                 fecdocumento datetime, adicional cree un campo (FecDocPrueba, Date) y re dirigí la consulta y el resultado sigue siendo el mismo.

Comment: En lo que yo te he presentado, se utiliza datetime. Pero y el campo fecha. Es que es muy extraño, porque el número de días que dice que reporta de diferencia, dicen que hay algo raro. ¿Tienes documentos duplicados? ¿El campo Fecha de la tabla fechas de que tipo es? ¿Cuando te conectas con el mismo usuario que la aplicación (ojo tiene que ser el mismo) que te devuelve select @@LANGUAGE

Comment: ya encontré la diferencia en días y se debe a que en mi tabla fechas tenía configurado hasta el 2024, ya acabo de ajustar la tabla fechas hasta el día de hoy y ya sale la información correcta.